# Computing Newtonian capacity of sets like intervals, discs?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, potential-theory

For a metric space $(E,\rho)$ the $a$-capacity is defined as $$\mathrm{Cap}_{a}(E)=\left[\inf\left\{\int \int \frac{d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)}{\rho(x,y)^{a}}:\mu\text{ probability measures on }E\right\}\right]^{-1}.$$

Newtonian Capacity: Set $E=\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $d\geq 3$ and $a=d-2$ i.e.

$$\mathrm{Cap}_{d-2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})=\left[\inf \left\{\int \int \frac{d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)}{\rho(x,y)^{d-2}}:\mu\text{ probability measures on }\mathbb{R}^{d}\right\}\right]^{-1}.$$

How can I compute the Newtonian capacity of Borel sets $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$? Specifically, of intervals, discs?

Since there can be infinite measures, how can we be sure we found the inf?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, the formulas you have define the minimal energy; the capacity is the reciprocal of that.

For a general set, there is no way to compute its Newtonian capacity analytically. One of rare exceptions is the ball $B=\{x : |x|\le R\}$. Based on the facts that the minimizing measure (i) exists; (ii) is unique; (iii) is supported on $\partial B$; one can conclude that it is the Lebesgue measure, by rotational symmetry.

But more often, the computation of capacity goes through the *potential* of the minimizing (equilibrium) measure, called the equilibrium potential:
$$U^\mu(x) = \int \frac{d\mu(y)} {|x-y|^{d-2}}$$
One can show that $U^\mu$ is *harmonic* on the complement of $E$ (this is not hard), decays like $|x|^{2-d}$ at infinity (this is clear), and is *constant* a.e. on $E$ (this is a nontrivial variational argument). Then the problem is to find such a function, i.e., solve a boundary value problem for the Laplacian. For nice sets (again, with a lot of symmetry) one can sometimes do this by separation of variables.

Once such $U$ is found, normalize it so that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|x|^{d-2} U(x)=1$; this amounts to normalizing the corresponding measure $\mu$. Then the value taken by $U$ on $E$ is exactly the capacity of $E$, since integration over $y$ will produce this value.

Recommended reading: *Foundations of modern potential theory* by Landkof, especially Chapter II. In section II.3 the author lists the values of the Newtonian capacity of several families of sets in $\mathbb R^3$. For example, the ball of radius $r$ has capacity $a/\pi$; the disk of radius $r$ has capacity $2a/\pi^2$; a line segment has capacity $0$.

Comment: any other references? I already have that one.